# Syncing iPhone 4S music only

Tags: data-synchronization, iphone

Will syncing iPhone delete existing photos on iPhone? I want to sync new songs but not sure if it will delete my valuable photos.

Answer (score 1):

From [Apple's Web site](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4236):

> To delete synced photos and videos
>
> In iTunes, select the device icon in the Devices list on the left. Click the Photos tab in the resulting window.
>
> Choose "Sync photos from."
>
> On a Mac, choose iPhoto or Aperture from the pop-up menu.
>
> On a Windows PC, choose Photoshop Album or Photoshop Elements from the pop-up menu.
> Choose "Selected albums" and deselect the albums or collections you want to delete.
> Click Apply.

So, the albums you want to KEEP should be selected. They will sync with your iTunes account.

However, I prefer to store my photos directly to Dropbox. Dropbox can be set up to automatically sync photos to it using their [Camera Upload](https://www.dropbox.com/help/289/en) feature.

Additionally, if you like the file system method, you can use an app like [Phoneview](https://www.ecamm.com/mac/phoneview/) to move photos manually into a directory of your choice.